# KeyError when storing a output from a json in a variable

Tags: python, json, url, request, keyerror

I'm trying to get an output url from a json (not a file) and store it in a variable, but, i'm always get a KeyError, and i don't know why, already tried everything, i think.

Code:

```
import requests

start_url = 'url_here'

r = requests.post(
    "https://api.deepai.org/api/deepdream",
    data={'image': start_url},
    headers={'api-key': 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'}
)
final_url = r.json()['output_url']
```

i get this message in the terminal:

```
final_url = r.json()['output_url']
KeyError: 'output_url'
```

it should just store it in the final_url variable, but it's not happening.
ps: already tried print(final_url), i get nothing.

can someone help me? Or clarify why that's happening? Thank you!

Comment: The json result does not contain a top-level key named `output_url`.

Comment: You should try: `result = r.json(); print(result)` This might tell you what is really going on.

Comment: @quamrana hey, thx, i tried it but i get the following output: ```{'err': 'error processing given inputs from request'} ```

Comment: Is that a standard error from requests?

Comment: Good question, idk, but i think is more related do DeepDream API than requests module